# How to fix validation constraints in embedded object beeing ignored?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

I have my entity object in Spring Boot & Hibernate REST API. This class has many fields. Part of them is embedded and validation constraints such as @Min @Max are not working on fields in @Embeddable class. Same validation rules work perfect in @Entity classes. I am using javax.validation.constraints.Max

My main object looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Notice extends BaseEntity {

  @Embedded
  private MyEmbeddedClass myEmbeddedClass;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_class_id")
  private MyEntityClass myEntityClass;

}
```

And my @embedded class:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddedClass {

  @Size(max = 50)
  private String label;

  @Max(100)
  private Integer percent;
```

}

@Max constraint on percent field is ignored, but @size is working perfectly

```
@Entity
public class MyEntityClass extends BaseEntity {

  @Size(max = 50)
  private String name;

  @Max(6000)
  private Integer size;
```

}

And here @Max constraint and @size constraint on fields size are beeeing created

Is there a way to fix this? My Spring boot version is 2.1.1 and I can create my database scripts manually but I'd like to avoid that and get almost perfect script thanks to hibernate

Comment: Not sure which `@Max` annotation you use, but it it happens to be `javax.validation.constraints.Max`, then you need to implement it like this: `@Max(value = 5000)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes it's from javax package but i've already tried this @Max(value = 5000) and still beeing ignored :/

Comment: I just read some docs about it and I think its the following. `@Size` works as it is a database column constraint as well (`varchar(50)`) whereas `@Min` or `@Max` are only on the client side as constraints (those don't exist in a database). This means that you need to `validate` the instance before you save it to database etc. For much more information on this topic, read [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-validating-bean-constraints)

Comment: Thank you for your interest but I've already found a solution! The problem was i had to use @Valid on my embedded fields. For example: ` @Embedded @Valid
  private MyEmbeddedClass myEmbeddedClass`. And now constraints are beeing created in scripts and in PostgreSQL. [docs](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess)

Answer (score 11):

You need to add `@Valid` annotation on your embedded object if you want to validate the constraints defined in your `@Embeddable` object:

```
@Entity
public class Notice extends BaseEntity {

    @Embedded
    @Valid
    private MyEmbeddedClass myEmbeddedClass;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I've just found a solution ( check comments  under my post) ;) But thanks